# Help Understanding Expectations, density and Radon Nikodym Theorem

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, radon-nikodym

I am trying to study probability and measure theory on my own, and I'm struggling to make the link between the Law of a Probability (distribution), the Radon Nikodym Theorem and the change of variables formula. Below I'll write down my current understanding of the topic; would someone mind filling in the gaps for me? Thanks

We'll begin with a probability space (more generally could have been a measure space but I want to work with probability measures), $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ where $\mathcal{F}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

We have a random variable, $X$, which maps from this space into the measurable space $(\mathbb{R},B(\mathbb{R}))$, where $B(\mathbb{R})$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$. By definition, we have that $X^{-1}(B) \in \mathcal{F}$ for all $B \in B(\mathbb{R})$.

We equip the measurable space with the distribution of the random variable, $Q_{X}: B(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow [0,1]$, which is defined as $Q(B) = \mathbb{P}(X^{-1}(B)) = \mathbb{P}(X \in B) = \mathbb{P}(\{\omega \in \Omega: X(\omega) \in B\})$ for all $B \in B(\mathcal{R})$.

We say that a measure $\nu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to a measure $\mu$, denoted $\nu << \mu$ if $\mu(A) = 0$ implies that $\nu(A) = 0$ for all $A \in \mathcal{F}$. Then the Radon Nikodym theorem tells us that if $\nu$ and $\mu$ are $\sigma$-finite, and $\nu << \mu$, then there exists a positive measurable $g:(\Omega, \mathcal{F}) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R},B(\mathbb{R}))$, such that $\nu(A) = \int_{A} g d\mu$. We call $g$ the density or Radon Nikodym derivative of $\nu$ with respect to $\mu$.

Ok so now I want to put all this theory together to understand the definition of an expectation or integral of a random variable that one would normally be taught in a first year undergraduate probability course. I'll try do this for continuous random variables (I should be able to get the result for the discrete case from that). In such basic probability courses, we are taught that $E(g(X)) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} g(x) Q_{X}dx$, where $Q_X$ is introduced as the PDF, which is just the Law or density described above.

My book defines the expectation of the random variable as $E(X) = \int_{\Omega} X d\mathbb{P}$, or using proper notation, $E(X) = \int_{\Omega} X(\omega) d \mathbb{P}(\omega)$. My question is how do you get from this definition to the one that makes use of the density as given in basic probability courses. Why is it that $E(X) = \int_{\Omega} X d\mathbb{P} = \int_{\mathbb{R}}x Q_X dx$? From what I've seen, I'm meant to use the Radon Nikodym theorem or a change of variables (I don't get this), but I don't understand how. I'm also not entirely sure I understand what $E(X) = \int_{\Omega} X d\mathbb{P}$ means either.

Thank you for the help

Comment: Change of variables says that $E(X) = \int_\Omega X\,dP = \int_{\mathbb R}x\,\mu(dx)$ where $\mu(B) = P(X\in B)$. If $\mu$ is dominated by the Lebesgue measure, then $\mu(dx) = f(x)dx$ or, equivalently, $\int_B d\mu = \int_B f(x)dx$ for some non-negative $f$. This suggests that $\int x\,\mu(dx) = \int xf(x)\,dx$. This is indeed true, the proof is just your standard (4 step) approximation argument.

Comment: @AndrewZhang Thanks! Can I clarify some notation please? Is $\int x \mu(dx)$ equivalent to $\int x d\mu$? If we write $E(X) = \int_{\Omega}X(\omega)dP(\omega) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} x \mu (dx)$, then are we saying that $x = X(\omega)$? Also, when you say that $\mu$ is dominated by the Lebesgue measure, then does this mean that $\mu$ is absolutely continuous w.r.t the Lebesgue measure? If thats the case, should it not be $\int_{B} d \mu = \int_{B} f(x) d \lambda(x)$? Sorry if these are silly Qs!

Comment: Yes, to all your questions. Regarding the last, it is customary to write $\int g(x)dx$ instead of $\int g(x)d\lambda(x)$ when integrating with respect to Lebesgue measure.

Comment: @AndrewZhang Thanks for the reply. I think I now understand most of this. I get that you first apply the change of variables to switch the integral from using $P$ to using $\mu$. Then you use the fact that $\mu << \lambda$ to write the integral using the Lebesgue measure. But I'm still confused by the final result. We end up with $E(X)  = \int_{\mathbb{R}} x f(x) dx$ but should the $f(x)$ not be the probability density function of $X$, instead of just some function? I thought that the PDF of $X$ was $\mu$, so should that $f(x)$ not actually be $\mu$?

Comment: Here I am using $\mu$ to denote the pushforward measure induced by $X$ on $(\mathbb R,\mathcal B(\mathbb R))$, namely $\mu(B) = P(X\in B)$. If $\mu\ll \lambda$, then $\mu$ has a Radon-Nikodym derivative $f$ such that $\mu(B) = \int_B f(x)\,dx$. One can show that $f(x) = F'(x)$ where $F(x) = P(X\leq x)$.

Comment: @AndrewZhang To use the language of a first basic course in probability, is $F(x)$ not just the CDF? Then the derivative of the CDF is just the PDF which is what you call the pushforward measure? So does that not mean that the Radon-Nikodym derivative f is just the PDF of X or in other words just the pushforward measure induced by X?

Comment: Let me clarify what I mean: F is just the pushforward measure in the case of $B = (-\infty, x]$. This is just the cumulative distribution function (CDF) and entirely characterises the pushforward measure (which is another name for density or PDF). Then from school we know that the derivative of the CDF is just the density. So if $f = F'$ does that not mean that $f(x) = \mu (x)$

Comment: Strictly speaking, an arbitrary measurable function $f:\mathbb R \to [0,\infty]$ is not a measure, though it does induce one, say by monotone convergence, and can thus be identified with the measure it induces. One way to denote this would be $(\mathbb R,\mathcal B(\mathbb R), f(x)\mu(dx))$ where $\mu$ is a Borel measure on the real line. So to answer your question, strictly speaking, the pdf and cdf are not the pushforward measure, though they can be identified as such. To your last point, $f(x) = \mu(x)$ is meaningless since $\mu$ is a measure. It is $f(x)dx=\mu(dx)$

Comment: To be clear, the pushforward measure is not defined as a Lebesgue density (i.e. pdf in your language). It can be identified as such when Radon-Nikodym is applicable, but it exists even when Radon-Nikodym is not applicable. The pushforward $\mu$ is a measure on $(\mathbb R,\mathcal B)$ induced by $X:(\Omega,\mathcal F,P)\to (\mathbb R,\mathcal B)$ given by $\mu(B) = P(X\in B)$.

Comment: @AndrewZhang Ahh ok I understand. It just happens to be the density when we use the Radon Nikodym theorem with the Lebesgue measure?

Comment: This was a truly incredible exchange to learn from. I've been self-studying all the above topics off and on for a long time but this exchange finally made certain things click that never clicked before.Thank you to Jamal and Andrew. Andrew: You should write a text if you haven't already. AFAIK, pushforward measures are not  even in most probability measure texts.